# merge 2 different query into one in INSERT (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, they are

```
name
- fname
- sport_id (FK)

sports
- id (PK)
- football
- basketball
```

so I did this for INSERT

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO name(fname)
    VALUES('$fname')");
mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO sprots(football, basketball)
    VALUES('$football','$basketball')");
```

is that correct? or I should merge them into one query? How about the relationship and id?

Comment: Insert `sports` table. then get last insert id then Insert `name` table. Game Over

Comment: First insert into `sports` table and then get the last inserted id and then insert into name table

Comment: I believe `INSERT INTO sprots` should be `INSERT INTO sports`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to First insert data into `sports` table and then get the last inserted id from `sports` table and then insert into name table

To get the last inserted id

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO sports(football, basketball) VALUES('$football','$basketball')");

$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli); 

mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO name(fname,sport_id ) VALUES('$fname','$last_id')");
```

Comment: is UPDATE work the same? is there something like mysqli_update_id?

Comment: well that will be a different question and by the way for update you should have the id already

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments:

```
// Insert into sports table
mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO sports(football, basketball)
    VALUES('$football','$basketball')");

// Get last inserted id (in sports table)
$sport_id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

// Insert it into name table
mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO name(sport_id,fname)
VALUES('$sport_id','$fname')");
```